# Documents are locked randomly in Lotus Notes database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a legacy Lotus Notes application that starts to randomly lock a document even though no one is opening the document. So when someone tries to edit a document, Notes will say that 'the document is locked by user1/Domain' but when I check with user1, the person does not have that document open and the admin or the user1 has to manually right click the document and select 'Unlock document'.

What would some suggestions to try to find out the cause of this problem?

Comment: Are there any agents running on that user's behalf?

Comment: I am not sure but this is not affecting only 1 user.

Answer (score 2):

If users aren't manually locking the documents, then there must be some code that is doing it on their behalf.  Look through the code for places where the `NotesDocument.Lock()` method is being used or the formula `@DocLock`

I would use the Design Synopsis feature to generate a report of all the forms, script libraries, and agents, and then do a text search for those methods/formulas.  That may help narrow down where the lock is occurring.

Or, if you wish to turn off document locking completely:

- Choose File - Application - Properties and click the Basics tab.
- Deselect "Allow document locking."

Comment: when you're in the list of view or other design elements, simply hit <ctrl-H> and it will search all of the design elements. far faster than dumping a synopsis and searching that.